Get the value of another variable based on maximum in another column
I have a dataset with sample sizes in different years and I'm trying to identify the year with the largest sample size. How can I get the below code to work? Presently maxYear only returns NA values.
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
tibble(site = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE),
       year = sample(c(2000:2005), 100, replace = TRUE),
       n    = sample(seq(1, 15, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% mutate(maxYear = year[max(n)])

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   site [6]
  site   year     n maxYear
  <chr> <int> <dbl>   <int>
1 H      2004     9      NA
2 V      2002    12      NA
3 Y      2000    11      NA
4 W      2003     3      NA
5 O      2003     4      NA
6 E      2001    15      NA


Use which.max: test_data %>% group_by(site) %>% mutate(maxYear = year[which.max(n)])

Thanks @M--! If you want to write this up as a an answer, I will accept it.

there's already a Q&A about this, I closed as a dupe. Cheers.

Ooops... looks like this has already been closed.
